# find_by_sql changes datatype of aliased columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, find-by-sql

A basic ActiveRecord query returns an unquoted id, for example:

> User.first.attributes => {"id"=>2, ...

In find_by_sql, the aliased columns are returned with values in quotes, see id in this case:

> all = User.find_by_sql("SELECT u.id as u_id from users u").first.attributes => {"u_id"=>"2"}

How can the quoting of values be avoided?

Comment: Why do you want to use `find_by_sql` and alias `id`?

Comment: need to union 3 select statements across several tables. alias allows me to determine which ids belong to what models, but then changes them to quoted strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_by_sql maps returned columns to object fields by name. If you return a different column name in resultset Rails have no way to know what type to return. (so it may map everything to string - wild guess)